# Setting Up Ecler Evo 5, MPC 5000 and Pro Tools 12

Tags: audio, firewire, midi, soundflower

I'm trying to set up the [Ecler Evo 5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000X18MLA) to read the [Akai MPC 5000](http://www.akaipro.com/product/mpc5000) via MIDI, and [Pro Tools 12](https://www.avid.com/US/products/pro-tools-software) to read the [Ecler Evo 5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000X18MLA) via FireWire. If anyone has a similar set up and knows the way to make these synchronize, help please.

Comment: Have you already tried simply hooking up the cables and seeing if it works?  (MIDI cable from MIDI out on MPC to MIDI in on Evo, and firewire from the firewire out on the Evo to your mac (I assume you are using mac, as you asked this question on the Apple SE site))

Comment: Correct, it recognizes the Ecler Evo 5 in pro tools and in audio midi setup on the mac, but can't seem to get pro tools 12 tracking the MPC 5000.